# The amount of comments gets out of control sometimes

Tags: discussion, comments, information-display

This may be one of those, "Is it just me?" questions that gets buried, but on some questions, there are a ton of comments.  And annoyingly enough, **enough comments are shown that they're just noise**.  The whole point of the "show comment" link and the fancy AJAX whizbangery is to keep the noise minimal, while showing you a *few* comments you might care about.

But a lot of times I go to a thread, and see a giant wall of comments blocking the answers.  I don't like it, sir.  Here are [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7572/why-do-incorrect-answers-keep-getting-accepted) [examples](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19890/visual-toys-for-so) and a screenshot:

[image: wall of comments]

Comment: How big is your monitor!? :)

Comment: Would it be ironic if lots of comments were posted here?

Comment: @Bill - Big.  I rotated the output and took a screenshot that way.  http://ritter.vg/misc/stuff/desk.jpg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think using Meta as an example is a bad idea. Comments here are going to overflow, and happen often since everything gets discussed, or someone needs to mention **ponies** and **waffles**

If it gets really out of hand we delete the comments. However the honest solution is just to ignore it if your not interest in reading them. It beats having 200 answers on a question to handle a discussion. IMHO.

As [mmyers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/13531/mmyers) pointed out, this is only on MSO. On the [S]OFU sites only the 5 top voted comments are displayed in this manner.

Comment: Also, only 5 comments are shown on the other sites (at least SO).

Comment: @mmyers Correct. Updated.

Comment: I never noticed SO limits it.  It'd be nice if meta did as well, but it's obvious this was specifically changed.

Answer (score 2):

Although I imagine that it may be a lot more intensive, I must admit I am a fan of the idea of threaded comments which can then be expanded outwards, and I think it would be useful to follow along the conversations as well.

Comment: (-1) Threaded comments? BLASPHEMY!

Comment: But, to clarify my comment. I think threaded comments are a bad idea, because if you have a stupid "thread head", then no one will expand it, which means thoughtful responses will be tucked away. So, instead people will just post "non-reply" comments with the "@TheTXI" tag, and the comments will get even messier.

Comment: {[(*1)]} | i like, and have always liked, the idea of threaded comments. While i respect Atwood's motivation for leaving them out of SO, I feel they would be a valuable addition to MSO and quite possibly future SE sites. **@devinb:** As opposed to the current system, where thoughtful-but-off-topic responses to stupid-and-off-topic "thread heads" hide relevant comments?

Comment: @Shog... yes?